# Как заменить цвет фона с помощью JS по нажатию кнопки Tab и при повторном нажатии вернуть ему изначальное состояние?

Tags: javascript, dom, keydown, addeventlistener

При нажатии на кнопку Tab меняется фон body.

```
const bodyType = document.querySelector('body');
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {

    if (event.code == 'Tab'){
       let colors = bodyType.style.background = 'rgb(36, 41, 46)';
    } 
      
  });
```

Как при повторном нажатии на кнопку Tab, сделать фон background = 'initial' . То есть в начальное состояние?
При последующем нажатии на Tab, background снова меняется на 'rgb(36, 41, 46)'. И так до бесконечности.
Решить нужно на чистом JS(без CSS, HTML и добавлении новых классов в body)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: if (event.which == 9) bodyType.style.background = bodyType.style.background == "" ? 'rgb(36, 41, 46)' : "";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const bodyType = document.querySelector('body');
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    let colors;
    if (event.code === 'Tab'){
        if (bodyType.style.background === '') {
            colors = bodyType.style.background = 'rgb(36, 41, 46)';
        } else {
            colors = bodyType.style.background = ''
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Все переключает . Но срабатывает только на 2 нажатия Tab . Как эту конструкцию сделать бесконечной?

Comment: Специально проверил, у меня всё ок в браузере работает. Так то клавиша Tab используется самим браузером, переназначть на Shift к примеру, тогда точно никаких конфликтов не будет

Comment: Извините , перепроверил , работает. Спасибо!